# Leading Zeros Missing While Doing Export

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata, and have following code:

```
SELECT
...
CAST(t1.atr AS VARCHAR(30))
...
FROM (
SELECT
...
COALESCE(sum(t1.atr),0) AS atr,
...
) AS t1
```

The problem is, when the value of the 'atr' is either 0 or 0.xy (or starts with 0), the output is '.00' and '.xy' respectively. 
I would like to have the following output: '0.00' and '0.xy' respectively.
Btw, I am doing export in csv format file in this step.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify a format for your `CAST`?

```
CAST(t1.atr AS VARCHAR(30) FORMAT 'ZZZZZZZZZ9.99')
```

Comment: Now I'm geeting the error msg: SELECT Failed. (3617) FORMAT 'ZZZZZZZZZ9.99' does not match the datatype

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
CAST(   CAST(t1.atr AS DECIMAL(13,4) FORMAT 'Z(9)9.99')   AS VARCHAR(30))
```